# Scraping website to retrieve html elements and associated styles

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, cheerio

I'm attempting to scrape websites to grab all elements withing a provided tag e.g. $('header') and their associated styles. 
Essentially loop through every element and grab it's associated css and dump it all into a file.

Currently I've setup the following:

```
// npm install --save request request-promise cheerio puppeteer

const rp = require("request-promise");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
var fs = require("fs");
const $ = require("cheerio");
const url = "url here";

puppeteer
    .launch()
    .then(function(browser) {
        return browser.newPage();
    })

    .then(function(page) {
        return page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0}).then(function() {
            return page.content();
        });
    })

    .then(function(html) {
        let header = $('#header', html);

        fs.writeFile("test.txt", header, (err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            console.log("Successfully Written to File.");
        });
    })

    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err)
    });
```

I'm stuck with how I would loop over all the children elements and grab their styles. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you could use method of `.children([selector])` , just saw in cheerio documentation , it would give array , you could use that I think and loop it, have you tried it ?

Answer (score 0):

In the cheerio, you can something loop event like below

```js
const result = $('.listing > tbody:nth-child(1) tr').each((i, item) => {
    const $item = $(item);
    const comicName = $item.find('td > a').text().trim();
});
```